# Is "=" an Operator?

Tags: terminology

I know that $+$, $-$, $\times$, and $/$ are all operators. But is $=$ an operator?

For example, in the equation:

> $5 \times 5 = 25$

I know $\times$ is an operator, but is $=$?

Comment: = is a relation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation

Comment: = can be an operator, in some computer languages, that returns "True" or "False".  In mathematics, however, it is a relation.

Comment: If you want to think of $=$ as an operator here, you have to then think of $5*5=25$ as an expression (the result of applying the $=$ operator). If you want to think of $5*5=25$ as a sentence that is either true or false, then consider $=$ as a relation.

Comment: They're all relations. A map or operator is a special relation, that is it must be coinjective and cosurjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mathematical jargon, an operator is usually a function that takes some members of a set $S$ (most often, but not always two members of $S$) and yields another member of the same set $S$.  $+, -,$ and $ \times$ are examples.

In contrast, the $=$ sign is not a function, and “$4=5$” cannot be evaluated to yield another number.  Instead, “$4=5$” is an *assertion* that $4$ and $5$ are equal.  The $=$ symbol denotes the *relation* of equality, and for each $a$ and $b$ one has either that $a=b$ is true or that it is false.

In computer programming languages, there is a more unified approach. There is a special set of “boolean values”, which are considered true and false, and which are *values*, in the same way that numbers are values.  In this view,  $=$ (and $<, >,$ and the rest) is considered to be a *function* whose result is either a true or a false value.
(Some languages even dispense with the special true and false values, and define `=` to be a function which yields the number $1$ if its arguments are equal and the number $0$ otherwise.)  In a computer programming language, one can typically write something like

```
(5 < 4) = (3 > 7)
```

which the computer will consider to yield a true value.  In the mathematical view, an expression like $(5<4)= (3>7)$ is at least puzzling, and probably meaningless, because mathematics does not usually construe relation symbols as representing functions.

Comment: What you refer to is that every relation can be sort of lifted up to another relation. This way you can turn **eeeverything** into a function. But that is not what is desired!!

Comment: Besides, there's a precise definition of what an operator is not only mathematical jargon - that is the equal sign is an operator!! *(I'm not bothering as I wrote an answer, too, but as this one is still being here.)*

Answer (score 1):

The '$=$' sign can be an treated as an operator if Iverson brackets convention is used. For example, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}[i=2] = 1$$ or
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}[gcd(i,n)=2]$$

Using this notation, each time the condition inside the brackets is true, $1$ is returned.

(See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Comment: The operator is the Iverson bracket, not the equals sign.

Comment: @egreg Why are Iverson brackets an operator? Isn't the equal sign a binary operator that operates on two values, $a$ and $b$? Inside the brackets we have a statement that is either true or false based on input $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, it is an operator!**

Usually - and that is the only way if encountered so far - is that equality is defined as relation within a set.
*(There is as well equality w.r.t. set theory but I guess that is a somewhat different story.)*

So first extend they're all relations; unary, binary, ternary, finitary and so on.

Now, in order to call it an operator or more generally a map it must be cosurjective and coinjective:
$$\forall a\in A\exists a_0\in A:\quad a=a_0$$
$$\forall a\in A:\quad a=a'\land a=a''\implies a'=a''$$
*(That is every element will be mapped somewhere and at most to one point.)*

But that is the case for the equality relation. So it is a map!
*(In fact, it is nothing but the identity map.)*

Comment: How is an operator a map?

Comment: Could I have someone verify this before I accept?

Comment: Operator and map are synonymous! Operator however is usually reserved for maps that additionally respect algebraic structure.